# python(OOPS) tkinter button not appearing

Tags: python, function, class, oop, tkinter

i am trying to make a library management system in python using oops and tkinter.
here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
class library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen=Tk()
        self.title='LOGIN'
        self.screen.minsize(800,600)
        self.screen.maxsize(800,600)
        self.screen.title(self.title)
        c=Canvas(self.screen,bg='black').place(x=-10,y=0,height=1000,width=1000)

    def screen_work(self):
        self.screen_login().screen.destroy()
        screen=Tk()
        screen.title('LIBRARY MANAGEMENT')
        #screen.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

    def button(self):
        Button(self.screen,text='press',bg='red').place(x=400,y=300)

    
lib=library()
mainloop()
```

now ,when i run this program a black screen of dimension '800x600; opens up without any errors but does not show any button.

Comment: You never call the `button` method.

Comment: As ever, @BryanOakley is correct and has beaten me to the punch! Try calling `self.button()` at the end of your `__init__` method (FWIW, you'll have the same problem with your `screen_work` method)

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Oakley and JRiggles rightly stated, the button function is never called, so it wouldn't display

updated code

```py
from tkinter import *
class library():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen=Tk()
        self.title='LOGIN'
        self.screen.minsize(800,600)
        self.screen.maxsize(800,600)
        self.screen.title(self.title)
        c=Canvas(self.screen,bg='black').place(x=-10,y=0,height=1000,width=1000)
    
    def screen_work(self):
        self.screen_login().screen.destroy()
        screen=Tk()
        screen.title('LIBRARY MANAGEMENT')
        #screen.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    def button(self):
        Button(self.screen,text='press',bg='red').place(x=400,y=300)

lib=library()
lib.button()
mainloop()
```

here's a great resource to learn tkinter in case you're interested!
https://realpython.com/python-gui-tkinter/

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really need to use a function to add a button, you may just leave the button code near the end after the other functions. If you want to keep the function, I think you forgot to declare the function in order for the button to appear.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).